# How do I optimize a Views "execute_count_query"?

Tags: 7, database, views

So, I was able to optimize a particularly nasty query in one of my views using mymodule_views_query_alter(), bringing it from 13 seconds down to about 200 milliseconds.  However, I see in my Devel query log there is an associated "[execute_count_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_pager.inc/function/views_plugin_pager%3a%3aexecute_count_query/7)" that Views automatically runs that does NOT contain my optimizations.  It is as if any count query ignores my hook overrides.  Thus, the count query continues to run up a 13 second call!  I've pasted it below in all its disgusting glory.

So, how in blazes do I get at this query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (
SELECT 1 AS expression FROM drupal_node node INNER JOIN (
SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid FROM drupal_taxonomy_term_data td 
INNER JOIN drupal_taxonomy_vocabulary tv ON td.vid = tv.vid 
INNER JOIN drupal_taxonomy_index tn ON tn.tid = td.tid 
WHERE (tv.machine_name IN (:db_condition_placeholder_7)) ) taxonomy_term_data_node ON node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node.nid 
LEFT JOIN drupal_taxonomy_vocabulary taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data_node.vid = taxonomy_term_data_node__taxonomy_vocabulary.vid 
LEFT JOIN drupal_field_data_field_published_at field_data_field_published_at ON node.nid = field_data_field_published_at.entity_id AND (field_data_field_published_at.entity_type = :views_join_condition_0 AND field_data_field_published_at.deleted = :views_join_condition_1) 
WHERE (( (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (node.nid IN (SELECT tn.nid AS nid FROM drupal_taxonomy_index tn 
LEFT OUTER JOIN drupal_taxonomy_term_hierarchy th ON th.tid = tn.tid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN drupal_taxonomy_term_hierarchy th1 ON th.parent = th1.tid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN drupal_taxonomy_term_hierarchy th2 ON th1.parent = th2.tid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN drupal_taxonomy_term_hierarchy th3 ON th2.parent = th3.tid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN drupal_taxonomy_term_hierarchy th4 ON th3.parent = th4.tid 
WHERE ( (tn.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) OR (th1.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_2) OR (th2.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_3) OR (th3.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_4) OR (th4.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_5) ))) )AND(( (node.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_6)) )))) subquery
```

Comment: it might help if you post your optimized views query, the count query should be very similar. I'm also interested in your hook_views_query_alter() code snippet since I'm struggling to get it to work myself. Thanks!

Comment: Try to abandon terms hierarchy this is a major complication of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know the query you want use in its place, you can override the count query for a view fairly easily. There are probably other places to do it but I found [`hook_views_pre_execute()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7) to work pretty well:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_execute($view) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_name' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
    $new_count_query = db_select('some_table', 't')
      ->fields('t', array('id'))
      ->condition('some_field', 'some_condition');

    $view->build_info['count_query'] = $new_count_query;
  }
}
```

Views will convert the above query into a `COUNT(*)` at some point further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)" filter  - use "Content: Has taxonomy term" instead and SELECT sub-query will not be used. This will dramatically increase performance of SQL-query.